# Container with 100% width

Tags: css

I've problem with my container.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIikn.png)

This container should has width: 100% and margin: 0 auto. Of course I write it down but it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<section class="testimonial">
    <div class="testimonial-info">
        <h2>Customer Testimonials</h2>
        <p>Here's what our customers say about working with us.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-box">
        <p>"Payment Solutions T/A SmartDebit have worked with The London Mint Office since we began to trade in the UK in 2006. They advised us on our payment processing platform from conception, implementation through to live processing of the major payment types. They worked with us side by side in setting up services with our Bank which proved invaluable. With SmartDebit’s assistance we moved from an outsourced fulfilment and call centre to our own establishment which involved complex development of payment systems involving the UK, Norway and Germany. Our activities since then have grown substantially and we continue to seek advice and service from SmartDebit. We set up Direct Debits at the outset and are now investigating developing this further into online processing. We have found the services reliable which is critical in our marketplace. They have a solid understanding of the payment processing business across the board."</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
 .testimonial
{
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px;
}

.testimonial p
{
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.testimonial-box
{   
    background-color: #006db6;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 40px;
}

.testimonial-box p
{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: and what about `padding: 40px;`? also no need width:100% with block elements

Comment: Wha is the intended result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your container is 100% the width of the .testimonial section, but the testimonial also has 40px padding. So your container is the full width of the section, + 40 px on the left.

One solution would be to give the .testimonial-box class a margin of 0 -40px, like so:

```css
.testimonial
{
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px;
}

.testimonial p
{
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.testimonial-box
{   
    background-color: #006db6;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 -40px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
}

.testimonial-box p
{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<section class="testimonial">
    <div class="testimonial-info">
        <h2>Customer Testimonials</h2>
        <p>Here's what our customers say about working with us.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-box">
        <p>"Payment Solutions T/A SmartDebit have worked with The London Mint Office since we began to trade in the UK in 2006. They advised us on our payment processing platform from conception, implementation through to live processing of the major payment types. They worked with us side by side in setting up services with our Bank which proved invaluable. With SmartDebit’s assistance we moved from an outsourced fulfilment and call centre to our own establishment which involved complex development of payment systems involving the UK, Norway and Germany. Our activities since then have grown substantially and we continue to seek advice and service from SmartDebit. We set up Direct Debits at the outset and are now investigating developing this further into online processing. We have found the services reliable which is critical in our marketplace. They have a solid understanding of the payment processing business across the board."</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

If you want to keep the 40px padding, you can simply remove the width:100%

```css
.testimonial
{
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px;
}

.testimonial p
{
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.testimonial-box
{   
    background-color: #006db6;
    padding: 20px 40px;
}

.testimonial-box p
{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<section class="testimonial">
    <div class="testimonial-info">
        <h2>Customer Testimonials</h2>
        <p>Here's what our customers say about working with us.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-box">
        <p>"Payment Solutions T/A SmartDebit have worked with The London Mint Office since we began to trade in the UK in 2006. They advised us on our payment processing platform from conception, implementation through to live processing of the major payment types. They worked with us side by side in setting up services with our Bank which proved invaluable. With SmartDebit’s assistance we moved from an outsourced fulfilment and call centre to our own establishment which involved complex development of payment systems involving the UK, Norway and Germany. Our activities since then have grown substantially and we continue to seek advice and service from SmartDebit. We set up Direct Debits at the outset and are now investigating developing this further into online processing. We have found the services reliable which is critical in our marketplace. They have a solid understanding of the payment processing business across the board."</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't see the need of all these complication with negative values .. he simply need to remove the width

Comment: Also a `div` is a block element by default.

Comment: Oops indeed! Wasn't thinking. Edited!

Answer (score 1):

Like Michael said, the issue is your padding.

See here for an explanation of how CSS calculates widths: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Imo, a more semantic/cleaner solution is simply specifying

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

On the 100% width div.